# Excel VBA Export Multiple sheets to PDF

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, excel-2010

I have been trying to export a named range on multiple worksheets to a single pdf. Initially, it seemed to work fine, then I noticed the the selected range would change when loading the various sheets into an array.

It is my understanding by using `Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat` this would export the selected cells only. Therefore, I have a macro to loop through the required sheets, select the various ranges need then create an array for all the sheets to allow exporting to a single pdf.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Dim toPrnt As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set srcSht = wb.Sheets("print_array")

Dim myArr1() As Variant
    myArr1 = srcSht.Range("myPrintArray")

Dim i As Long
Dim j As String
    For i = LBound(myArr1, 1) To UBound(myArr1, 1)
            j = myArr1(i, 1)

    wb.Sheets(j).Activate
        wb.ActiveSheet.Range("CCB_" & Left(j, 5) & "_Print").Select

    Next i

wb.Sheets(Array("CAT01 - Request for Resource", _
                            "CAT02 - Resource Allocation", _
                            "CAT03 - Product Data Sources", _
                            "CAT04 - Target & Control Cells", _
                            "CAT05 - Matching And Deduping", _
                            "CAT06 - Exclusions", _
                            "CAT07 - Data from other teams", _
                            "CAT08 - Outputs", _
                            "CAT09 - Special Instructions", _
                            "CAT10 - Brief Meeting Sign Off" _
                            )).Select

Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDF_FileAndPath, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

When stepping through the code, everything goes to plan right up to creating the sheets array, at this point the selected ranges change.

I have also tried using PageSetup, but the result is the same.

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    .FitToPagesTall = 1
    .PrintArea = Range("CCB_" & Left(j, 5) & "_Print").Address
End With
```

After reviewing a few similar post in this forum, I am still at a loss.

Can anyone shed light on why the selected range changes when creating the array or, have any other suggestions that may help?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem by copying the selected ranges to a temporary file then exporting from there. The complete solution looks like this...

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Dim tempFile As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set srcSht = wb.Sheets("print_array")

Dim myArr1() As Variant
    myArr1 = srcSht.Range("myPrintArray")

Dim i As Long
Dim j As String
    For i = LBound(myArr1, 1) To UBound(myArr1, 1)
            j = myArr1(i, 1)

    wb.Sheets(j).Activate

    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .PaperSize = xlPaperA4
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
        .PrintArea = Range("CCB_" & Left(j, 5) & "_Print").Address
    End With

        Next i

    wb.Sheets(Array("CAT01 - Request for Resource", _
                                "CAT02 - Resource Allocation", _
                                "CAT03 - Product Data Sources", _
                                "CAT04 - Target & Control Cells", _
                                "CAT05 - Matching And Deduping", _
                                "CAT06 - Exclusions", _
                                "CAT07 - Data from other teams", _
                                "CAT08 - Outputs", _
                                "CAT09 - Special Instructions", _
                                "CAT10 - Brief Meeting Sign Off" _
                                )).copy

                With ActiveWorkbook
                    .Save

                    tempFile = .FullName

                    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDF_FileAndPath, _
                        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
                        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

                    .Close

                End With

                Kill tempFile

   End If
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.  I came across another, easier solution.  No need for temp files.

After you .select your array, instead of **Selection**.ExportAsFixedFormat, use **ActiveSheet**.ExportAsFixedFormat.  Because your sheets are made active with your initial .select, ActiveSheet then selects all desired sheets to export.

Your code should look like this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim srcSht As Worksheet
Dim toPrnt As String

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set srcSht = wb.Sheets("print_array")

Dim myArr1() As Variant
    myArr1 = srcSht.Range("myPrintArray")

Dim i As Long
Dim j As String
    For i = LBound(myArr1, 1) To UBound(myArr1, 1)
            j = myArr1(i, 1)

    wb.Sheets(j).Activate
        wb.ActiveSheet.Range("CCB_" & Left(j, 5) & "_Print").Select

    Next i

wb.Sheets(Array("CAT01 - Request for Resource", _
                            "CAT02 - Resource Allocation", _
                            "CAT03 - Product Data Sources", _
                            "CAT04 - Target & Control Cells", _
                            "CAT05 - Matching And Deduping", _
                            "CAT06 - Exclusions", _
                            "CAT07 - Data from other teams", _
                            "CAT08 - Outputs", _
                            "CAT09 - Special Instructions", _
                            "CAT10 - Brief Meeting Sign Off" _
                            )).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=PDF_FileAndPath, _
Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
```