Exporting a single sheet and range as multiple pages of PDF
I have written a Macro script which takes a select group of sheets in an excel file and exports them all as a single PDF document. However, there are cases where the recipient of these documents needs multiple copies of certain pages within this combined pdf. I am wondering if I would be able to set it so that certain sheets have duplicate pages within the final exported PDF.
For example, suppose sheet1 is one of the sheets that goes into the final PDF. I would want to find a way to have it so that the page from sheet1 is duplicated multiple times.
Here is the raw code for the macro along w/ a helper function it uses:
Sub ExportToPDF()
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim mds As Worksheet
    Set mds = wb.Sheets("Master Data Sheet")
    
    Dim DefaultSheets, SelectedSheets As Variant
    DefaultSheets = Array("Proforma Invoice", "SLI", "VGM Form", "Commercial Invoice", "Cert of Origin", "Packing List")
    
    Dim Country, Company, CurrDate, OrderNo, FilePath As String
    Country = mds.Range("E49").Value
    Company = mds.Range("D36").Value
    CurrDate = mds.Range("E46").Value
    OrderNo = mds.Range("E39").Value
    
    For Each Sheet In Array("Master Data Sheet", "Multi Order Queries", "Packing List Query")
        wb.Worksheets(Sheet).Visible = xlSheetHidden
    Next
    
    FilePath = GetFolder()
    
    wb.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        Filename:=FilePath + "\" + Company + "_" + OrderNo + "_" + CurrDate + ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
    For Each Sheet In Array("Master Data Sheet", "Multi Order Queries", "Packing List Query")
        wb.Worksheets(Sheet).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next
    
    mds.Activate

Helper:
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function


Not sure the regular PDF export supports what you want.  You may need to create temporary copies of the repeated sheet(s) and then remove them following the export.

How many is "multiple" (3? 300?) and what would control how many copies were needed?

Have you had a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597511/excel-vba-export-multiple-sheets-to-pdf#:~:text=I%20managed%20to%20solve%20my%20problem%20by%20copying%20the%20selected%20ranges%20to%20a%20temporary%20file%20then%20exporting%20from%20there.%20The%20complete%20solution%20looks%20like%20this...

@TimWilliams the excel doc as a sheet called "Master Data Sheet" that we can store values on. The idea would be somewhere in the range of single digits numbers of duplicates.

This works for me - create required number of copies of the sheet, export, then remove the copies.
Note you don't need to hide the other sheets if you only export the selected worksheets.
Sub ExportToPDF()
    
    Const WSTOCOPY As String = "SLI" 'for example: the sheet to be copied
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, mds As Worksheet, wsName, first As Boolean
    Dim DefaultSheets, SelectedSheets As Variant, NumCopies As Long, i As Long
    Dim Country As String, Company As String, CurrDate As String
    Dim OrderNo As String, FilePath As String, wsCopy As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Set mds = wb.Sheets("Master Data Sheet")
    
    DefaultSheets = Array("Proforma Invoice", "SLI", "VGM Form", _
                          "Commercial Invoice", "Cert of Origin", _
                          "Packing List")
    
    Country = mds.Range("E49").Value
    Company = mds.Range("D36").Value
    CurrDate = mds.Range("E46").Value
    OrderNo = mds.Range("E39").Value
    
    NumCopies = mds.Range("B5").Value 'for example
    
    Set wsCopy = wb.Worksheets(WSTOCOPY)
    CreateCopies wsCopy, NumCopies 'create any required copies
    
    first = True
    For Each wsName In DefaultSheets
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Select first 'if true then replaces current selection
        first = False                                '   otherwise adds the sheet to the current selection
        If wsName = wsCopy.Name Then
            For i = 1 To NumCopies - 1 'select all the copies of the sheet
                wb.Worksheets(wsCopy.Index + i).Select first
            Next i
        End If
    Next wsName
    
    FilePath = GetFolder()
    
    'export only selected sheets
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
        Filename:=FilePath + "\" + Company + "_" + OrderNo + "_" + CurrDate + ".pdf", _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
    RemoveCopies wb 'remove any copies
    
    mds.Select
    
End Sub

'Create copies of worksheet `wsRep`
Sub CreateCopies(wsRep As Worksheet, totalCopies As Long)
    Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = wsRep
    For i = 1 To totalCopies - 1
        wsRep.Copy after:=ws
        Set ws = wsRep.Parent.ActiveSheet '#fixed for hidden sheets
        ws.Name = wsRep.Name & "_COPY" & (i + 1)
    Next i
End Sub

'remove all worksheets in `wb` where name contains "_COPY"
Sub RemoveCopies(wb As Workbook)
    Dim i As Long
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For i = wb.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        With wb.Worksheets(i)
            If UCase(.Name) Like "*_COPY*" Then .Delete
        End With
    Next i
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub


I am going to test this out but wow yeah that looks like it should fix the problem for me. Will report back. Thanks!

Following up and this did in fact work for me. Thanks again for the answer!

Good to hear it's working out.

Hey I have a follow up question. After testing this on another excel document (a backup version of course), it seems to apply the name change to the wrong sheets. Is there another way to go about that?

Does your new file have any hidden worksheets?  Or can you provide an example of what's going wrong?

Yes. How the file works is there are templates for the different documents (i.e Proforma Invoice) and sometimes specific countries have their own template. I have another (pretty long) Macro script which pulls the country an order is going to and unhides the relevant sheets. The unused sheets are hidden.

I think the only issue I have is the name change part. The copies are made, and I think based on the default name they have, which appends (copy#) to the copied sheet's name it should be fairly easy for me to retool your code. I'll report back on what I find. Thanks again for all the help.

I made a change in CreateCopies - try that out.

Ah there we go! Works now.

OK good.  I did wonder about hidden sheets when I wrote the initial version - should have fixed it then...
